# How to replace the specific value by using sed command

Tags: regex, linux, perl, sed

I would like to know what is the regular expression in sed command to search `$a` value from `"x"` file and replace with `$b` value.

```
$a="o=SAR-9|csa_6fe_2ge_v2_r1:3|csa_16ds1_e1_r2|csa_ds3e3_4_r1|csa_aux_alarm|csa_oc3cc_4_r1|csa_oc3_2_asap_r1|csa_oc3cc_4_r1|"

$b="SAR-18"
```

I tried to use below commands to search and replace the value but it didn't work in perl script. So i am looking for regular expression in sed to match `$a` value.

```
sed -i s/$a/$b/g <file-name>
```

Comment: Please don't use `$a` and `$b`. It may have negative effects on uses of `sort`.

Answer (score 3):

In Perl,

```
# Generate a regex pattern that matches the string in $a
my $a_re = quotemeta($a);

s/$a_re/$b/
```

The above can be shortened to

```
s/\Q$a\E/$b/
```